# Make website support older browsers jQuery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit stuck here. I have a website that currently uses jQuery 2.1.4 only. I just figured out it won't support older browsers such as IE 6, 7 and 8. I use jQuery for many things in my website, which includes login system, live chat and some management functions.

Anyway, I was thinking of implementing jQuery 1.11.3 because it supports these browsers. Thing is, I don't really know where to start from because I don't think I simply add another script source for jQuery 1.11.3 and it shall fix it all, but I'm looking for a way to add it so I won't have to change all my functions or add special functions just for older browsers.

The only jQuery methods I use are `$.ajax`, `$.when` and `$.then`.

Comment: I've had good results using jQuery 1.8 with IE Quirks Mode.  Check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), but I think it supports your frequently used methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think I simply add another script source for jQuery 1.11.3 and it shall fix it all

You just replace the existing script source with it.

The 2.1.x branch is just the 1.11 branch with all the slow compatibility code for old browsers removed. They are API compatible.

Comment: Is it slowing it much though?

Comment: It slows it enough that the jQuery team thought it was worthwhile maintaining two branches.

Comment: Can I use both versions and just detect if the browser is not IE 6,7 or 8 and use `.coConflict()` method? Will it make it faster for certain browsers?

Comment: Then you'll have to load both versions which will probably be even less efficient.